# R knitr - Show value of numeric variable in output, not variable name

Tags: r, variables, knitr

In my knitr document I create a vector, which contains a single number, e.g.

```
x <- 25
```

Later on I'd like to use this number in a chunk for some calculations:

```
sqrt(x)
```

When I now create a pdf document, it will show `sqrt(x)`. However, I'd like to make it showing `sqrt(25)` instead, i.e. I'd like to force knitr to output the content of x instead of the vector name (x) itself. How can this be done? Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1):

if your problem is just the visualisation, so the sqrt(x) doesn't actually calculate anything, then I think the following will work:
sqrt(`r x`). So the  `r x` will show the value that is stored in x.